# How to merge documents on a grouping condition and create a new field in mongo collection?

Tags: mongodb, robo3t

It is a data migration in a mongo db collection.

It is a data migration in a mongo db collection. 
In the code below, I have some documents. 
On the basis of common field1, all the documents should be grouped and merged to a single document. In the new merged document I want a new field4 which is actually a list of field2 and field3 objects from the group. And field2 and field3 fields should not be there in the single merged document.

In this way my document count would be reduced in the collection on the basis of unique field1.

*Document 1*
*{
    "field1" : "e8b0f2b5-de4a-4449-b2aa-15f009ac4978",
    "field2" : "9911",
    "field3" : "a"
}*

*Document 2*
*{
    "field1" : "e8b0f2b5-de4a-4449-b2aa-15f009ac4978",
    "field2" : "1100",
    "field3" : "b"
}*

*Document 3*
*{
    "field1" : "e8b0f2b5-de4a-4449-b2aa-15f009ac4978",
    "field2" : "0099",
    "field3" : "c"
}*

## Expected outcome

should be 1 document in a format

*{

   "field1":"e8b0f2b5-de4a-4449-b2aa-15f009ac4978",
   "field4":[

      {

         "field2":"9911",
         "field3":"a"
      },
      {

         "field2":"1100",
         "field3":"b"
      },
      {

         "field2":"0099",
         "field3":"c"
      }
   ]
}*

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregation pipeline with `$group` and `$push`

aggregation pipeline

```
db.t41.aggregate([
    {$group : {
        _id : "$field1", 
        field4 : {$push : {field2 : "$field2", field3 : "$field3"}}
    }},
    {$project : {_id : 0, field1 : "$_id", field4 : "$field4"}}
]).pretty()
```

collection

```
> db.t41.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c34260a4ffb628e45e69c00"), "field1" : "e8b0f2b5-de4a-4449-b2aa-15f009ac4978", "field2" : "9911", "field3" : "a" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c34260a4ffb628e45e69c01"), "field1" : "e8b0f2b5-de4a-4449-b2aa-15f009ac4978", "field2" : "1100", "field3" : "b" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5c34260a4ffb628e45e69c02"), "field1" : "e8b0f2b5-de4a-4449-b2aa-15f009ac4978", "field2" : "0099", "field3" : "c" }
>
```

result

```
> db.t41.aggregate([{$group : {_id : "$field1", field4 : {$push : {field2 : "$field2", field3 : "$field3"}}}}, {$project : {_id : 0, field1 : "$_id", field4 : "$field4"}}]).pretty()
{
        "field1" : "e8b0f2b5-de4a-4449-b2aa-15f009ac4978",
        "field4" : [
                {
                        "field2" : "9911",
                        "field3" : "a"
                },
                {
                        "field2" : "1100",
                        "field3" : "b"
                },
                {
                        "field2" : "0099",
                        "field3" : "c"
                }
        ]
}
>
```

**EDIT-1**

this works without hard-coding the keys

```
db.t41.aggregate([
    {$group : { _id : "$field1", data : {$push : {$objectToArray : "$$ROOT"}}}}, 
    {$addFields : {data : {$map : {input : "$data", as : "d", in : {$arrayToObject : {$slice : ["$$d", 2, {$size : "$$d"}]}}}}}}
]).pretty()
```

aggregation pipeline

```
> db.t41.aggregate([{$group : { _id : "$field1", data : {$push : {$objectToArray : "$$ROOT"}}}}, {$addFields : {data : {$map : {input : "$data", as : "d", in : {$arrayToObject : {$slice : ["$$d", 2, {$size : "$$d"}]}}}}}}]).pretty()
{
        "_id" : "e8b0f2b5-de4a-4449-b2aa-15f009ac4978",
        "data" : [
                {
                        "field2" : "9911",
                        "field3" : "a"
                },
                {
                        "field2" : "1100",
                        "field3" : "b"
                },
                {
                        "field2" : "0099",
                        "field3" : "c"
                }
        ]
}
>
```

Comment: What if we have one more field5, and the unique combination of field1 and field5 should be the condition. There are so many other fields as well, so I just want to keep the latest document and it's other fields from the group as it is?

Comment: Most importantly if I am correct aggregration is for representation purpose, though I am looking to migrate/restructure my db.

Comment: @Kusum please see the edit, if you want to restructure collection you may want to `$out` the results to a new collection